# How do you get the list of settings for a particular hive job?

Tags: hadoop, hive

By settings I mean things like hive.cbo.enable=true and other similar properties. I will be running these queries in an environment that has multiple concurrent jobs, and I was wondering how to do this for individual jobs using jobid or name.

Comment: Are you using Tez, Spark, or MapReduce execution?

Comment: Tez and MapReduce

Comment: In the Tez UI of a particular job, it believe you can see the environment of those tasks

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
hive> SET;
```

set prints all the variables in the namespaces hivevar, hiveconf,
system, and env.

Example out put looks like

```
hive.stats.retries.wait=3000
env:TERM=xterm
system:user.timezone=America/New_York
```

You can also use `hive> set -v;`

With the -v option, it also prints all the properties defined by Hadoop,
such as properties controlling HDFS and MapReduce

If you want to get/display a specific value then you need to specify it as below (set namespace:variable-name)

```
hive> set hiveconf:hive.cbo.enable;
hiveconf:hive.cbo.enable=true
```